# Secure javascript client or java server that hosts rest services with keycloak ? (Please read the description)

Tags: rest, spring-boot, multi-tenant, keycloak

Sorry about the vague question. 
So I have an apache webserver that is running my website. I use oracle jet for the website. I have already authenticated the website using keycloak, I put the authentication code within my javascript application and not on the top of apache web server. 
Now, I want to send rest requests to my spring boot server from my website and want to include the keycloak login information so that I can both authenticate and also hit the right database schema through spring boot (multi tenancy). 
Is it important to authenticate the rest service or just let it pass and just add a login id as a header ? And what is the best way to do this..

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

-Vikram

Comment: It should be enough to register your spring boot application as a client in the same realm and setup the spring boot application either with the keycloak spring boot adapter or the keycloak spring security adapter. Then you only need to append the Authentication header for each of the requests you make from the website with the current access token.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Thanks. And what about multi tenancy on spring boot ? could the authentication header also provide tenant information ?

Comment: What do you call tenant information?

Comment: @XtremeBiker for example, the tenant id that will help springboot identify the right database schema for the logged in user..

Comment: If it is something you're already sending from your website there's no problem with that. What the Spring Boot application would need will be the authorization header to check for its validity and grant you the access for the resource.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Thanks, I will try to implement it this way and let you know if I have problems.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I tried your approach. I registered my spring boot app as a client in the same realm and setup the application with keycloak spring boot adapter.
But the problem is with the communication between the website and the springboot app through rest urls. I tried to use the keycloak javascript adapter with no luck. How exactly do I append the authentication header to the requests that I am trying to make ? it looks like the rest urls are redirected to the login page when accessed from the website. From the browser, it works fine ...

Comment: You need to use either the keycloak spring Boot or spring security adapter, as the page is not accesed thorugh Browser, but from Rest.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Hi, it still does not work. I get no state cookie errors when I try to access the url throught the browser and CORS blocks my website otherwise. I have allowed all origins on the key cloak client but makes no difference..

Comment: @XtremeBiker Could you please answer this question ? I think you might be able to help me..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724191/implementing-schema-based-multi-tenancy-in-springboot-application-that-is-secure