# Implementing schema based multi tenancy in springboot application that is secured using keycloak

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, keycloak

I have a springboot application linked to a postgresql database. The app is secured using keycloak (keycloak springboot adapter). The idea is to have multiple schemas in the postgres database for different groups of users that login. I hope to identify the user-group using the keycloak token that is received by rest endpoints on the springboot server and then access the respective schema.

Where should I start ? Can anyone point me to a guide for this ? or is there any other better approach ? Any help would be appreciated.

edit :: 
Let me try narrowing it down a bit. Lets say the db has the schemas : public, tenant1, tenant2, tenant3.  In the keycloak server, I have two clients in the same realm, one for spring boot app and one for my website. I have 3 groups. group 1 has users A and B, group 2 has users C and D, group 3 has users E and F. If the user A logs into the website, he has a keycloak token that is going to help him get the data through ajax requests from the springboot server. I assume that, the incoming ajax request could provide the kc token which would tell spring boot that user A is requesting the data and he belongs to group 1. Here, I want the spring boot server to figure out that the data has to be fetched from the schema "tenant1" and do accordingly. Similarly, group 2 should be directed to tenant2 and group 3 to tenant 3. I want support on the part where the spring boot has to figure out the user and the group and access the right schema..
Cheers,
Vikram

Comment: This is a too broad question. On the one hand, it covers the DB design part, on the other one, the technical part of retrieving user groups using the KC spring boot adapter. Definitely you can do this in many, many ways.. I suggest you narrowing down your problem and trying to be specific (for example you tell nothing about the user attributes that need to be stored). If you happen to have any technical concrete problem, then that's what stack overflow is useful for.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Hi, I have edited the question and mentioned a more specific issue. Please let me know if this is any better..

Comment: And do you have any specific reason to do it in different DB schemas? I see little benefit on it and it would require many extra configuration steps to manage them. Also, why not use a single KC client instead of two?

Comment: @XtremeBiker Because different tenants are gonna have the same tables but with different data. It is basically gonna treat groups as organizations, the data needs to be separated. You mean the spring boot app and the website app can use the same KC client ?

Comment: Sure they can, if you use the Spring Boot adapter. In the case you treat groups as organizations, then you need to stop to think before implementing it. Do you need the data to be completely isolated one from the other (because of data protection, or so)? If not, go with a single schema. In case of different schemas, I would think of it a different way, it might be much better just to have many application instances for each of the organizations, so as each application access only a single DB schema.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Yes, it is got data protection.. The reason why we are looking at different schemas in the same database..

Comment: @XtremeBiker so anything about the complicated approach ?

Comment: I would just try to go the easy way.

Comment: @XtremeBiker thanks. Please let me know if you come across a guide or something similar for what I want to do..

Comment: @XtremeBiker any ideas on this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521077/keycloak-multi-tenancy-implementation-with-login-through-javascript-a-webpage