# Keycloak Multi Tenancy implementation with login through javascript (a webpage)

Tags: javascript, keycloak

I want to assign different realms to different clients (organisations) in keycloak. The login to keycloak is achieved through a webpage which acquires a valid token from keycloak which is then passed with the rest requests that I make from my website.
 Now, the javascript adapter needs a keycloak configuration file that has details about the realm that I want to log in to. But, the problem is that I do not know which realm the user belongs to because he / she can be from any organisation ie. the login page for all organisations is the same. 
What is the best way to achieve this ? I assume that this kind of approach is quite common these days but cannot find a solution..

Regards,
Vikram

Comment: This might be too late but you can consider using different subdomains for different organisations if that works for you.

Comment: @kaptan Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. I am just using different groups in the same realm as different organisations..
Do you have any experience witht the keycloak admin client ?

Comment: No I am not a pro on Keycloak.